# Using Orbeon Forms, is it possible to group radio buttons into radiogroups?

Tags: orbeon

I would like to be able to create a radio button list where radio buttons are contained in a radiogroup with a heading. Such as using the `<optgroup label="">` in HTML select lists or a `<fieldset> <legend>...</legend> ... </fieldset>`.

I still need to be able to return a single value across all groups, so separate lists would not be a solution.

e.g. for a list of cities grouped by their country...

```
USA
  New York
  San Francisco
  Seattle
  Miami
UK
  London
  Birmingham
  Manchester
  Cardiff
  Edinburgh
France
  Paris
  Toulouse
China
  Beijing
  Shanghai
Germany
  Berlin
  Munich
  Frankfurt
```

What would you advise to achieve this? Creating a custom XBL seems to me as the best solution so far, but I am not sure how to go about it after reviewing some of the existing select XBLs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you're asking this question in the context of accessibility. If you're using a regular `<xf:select1 appearance="full">` with an `<xf:label>`, Orbeon Forms will put all the radio buttons inside a `<span>` that has a:

- `role="radiogroup"`, e.g. so screen readers know that the content is a "group of radio buttons".
- `aria-labelledby="…"` pointing to the id of the element that contains the label for this control, e.g. so screen readers can properly read the label for "control".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, @avernet.    I was asking more in the context of layout.  So in the example above, the countries would be sub-headings (without a radio button) which relate to the group of controls below.

Comment: Putting it another way, would it be possible to have lots of radio groups which are all bound to a single element node in the form model?

Comment: @jtb I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but if you have different groups of checkboxes, as in your example one for US, UK, etc, and each group is implemented with its own `<xf:select1>`, but all with a `ref="…"` pointing to the same node, then they will work as you would expect: if the *San Francisco* radio is selected in the first, and a user selects *London* in the second, then *San Francisco* will unselect itself. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct functionality but I would like to insert sub-headings above each grouping (eg country names in the example above). The sub-headings should not have a radio button.

Comment: I have found a solution by creating an XBL component with its own data model, so in effect I am looping through each sub-heading and generating a xf:select1 control for each group which uses single-node-binding.

Comment: @jtb OK, great I am glad you found a solution, and thank you for the update.